# Windows Partitions don't allow me to create a Kali Linux partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, kali-linux

My Windows 10 is an MBR style legacy mode System. Recently I have decided to learn some hacking and hence decided to install Kali linux. I wanted it to dual boot with my Win 10. I have a 500 GB Hard drive. It has Three partitions, C for windows installation, D and E for storing data however E contains my programs such as Pycharm, toolbar etc. My D is nearly Empty. I have recently formatted my computer. There is one more system reserved partition. I shrinked my 190 GB C drive an created 30 GB of unallocated space. When I was installing Kali Linux and reached the Partition part, the space was defined as unusable. I didn't got what has happened and then I decided to make the unallocated space a volume. After performing this action the installer still displayed unusable space. Is this due to the fact that mbr can't get more than four partitions. If so, what should i do. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit1 - Here is the screen shot of my disk management
[Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s860U.png)

Comment: Yes, with a Windows install, you can't have more than 4 primary partitions/volumes, or 3 plus an extended partition where you can create logical/virtual drives, and since it's the Windows installer that wrote your MBR, you'll have either to format the whole drive and install Kali first, then re-partition to install Windows alongside, or get rid of your D drive if you can.

Comment: @Didier Your comment is confusing. The 4 partition limit is not imposed by Windows, it's a MBR limitation. The second part I don't understand at all, what does Windows installer have to do with this?

Comment: Please post a screenshot from _Disk management_ (right-click Start button -> _Disk management_)

Comment: The "four partition limitation" isn't *just* imposed by the MBR itself, but by the interpretation Microsoft does of the MBR guidelines and pre-requisites: when you install or reinstall Windows after formatting your drive, the Windows installer will create as many partitions as it *can*, not as it *needs*, to properly install Windows. Very often, it'll add two small partitions on top of the system one, and this for no *technical* reason. It's a commercial move by Microsoft that started with Vista, when it became apparent that Windows users were dual-booting Linux more and more...

Comment: @Didier Sir but I would like to keep at least three drives o sort out my data. Can I switch to GPT without losing any data?? If yes than how, will this sort my problem

Comment: If you Windows 10 is 64-bit, and there's a good chance that it is, though there are 32-bit Windows installed on 64-bit-capable platforms in budget PCs, then you should be able to convert your system drive to GPT without data losse, PROVIDED your PC can boot in UEFI mode. At the beginning of your question, you mention that it's currently booting an MBR in Legacy mode, but maybe UEFI can be enabled in the BIOS, in which case you could convert your MBR into GPT. Check this free tool: https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/will-converting-mbr-to-gpt-erase-all-the-disk-partitions.html

Comment: @Didier Sir as far as I know I don't think so my computer is a UEFI computer as the BIOS doesn't has a Secure boot option. In case if you want to check, and I would really appreciate if you do so, here is my motherboard- (https://www.amazon.in/Zebronics-Motherboard-ZEB-G31-Socket-775/dp/B019N24Q6O ) Also as far as I don't lose a lot of data, i.e. my programs in E drive or something like formatting the PC, I will have no issues. I have got time limits bound with me as I am an IGCSE student and my online classes are still going on. This year I have my IGCSE exam and hence don't have much time...

Comment: It's hard to say if your mobo supports UEFI or not, it's so exotic. Based on the socket, I'd say no, plus (and here I'm not sure, others may know better), I *believe* UEFI doesn't support DDR2, starts at DDR3 (to be confirmed), so even though your CPU (if it's indeed a C2D) does support UEFI, your mobo won't, which means you are stuck with MBR, and will have to save your data somewhere before deleting one of your 4 existing partitions.

Comment: So can't I convert to GPT without Losing all of my data. Few data loss is absolutely fine

Comment: You don't need to. Use the Kali manual to Install. Kali revealed 1st edition. Has Instructions for you to do this.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Sir do you mean the manual method of partitioning present in kali?? If so, I did mention that the space is being showed as unusable in the question itself. Can you please be a little more clear about the 1st edition and instructions you are talking about, I am using 2020.1 installer for kali. Any help would be appreciated